# Prove that $f_n(x) = n / (nx + 1) $ is pointwise convergent on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

> Prove that $f_n(x) = n / (nx + 1) $ is pointwise convergent on $(0,1)$.

I know that the pointwise limit will be $1/x$ but I want to do it using the $\epsilon$ definition of convergence of a sequence of functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think its pointwise limit is $1/x$ for every $x \in ]0,1[$.
To justify this, taking any $x \in ]0,1[$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$. We have
$$
\big| \frac{n}{nx+1} - \frac{1}{x} \big| = \frac{1}{nx^{2}+x} < \frac{1}{nx^{2}} < \varepsilon
$$
if $n > 1/\varepsilon x^{2}$,
so taking $N := \lceil \frac{1}{\varepsilon x^{2}} \rceil$ suffices.

Answer (score 0):

$|\frac{n}{nx+1} - \frac{1}{x}| = |\frac{-1}{x(nx+1)}| \leq |\frac{1}{nx^2}|$

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given.

Let $N = \frac{\epsilon}{x^2} $

What happens when $n > N$?

Answer (score -1):

Given $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in (0,1)$ choose $N\in \mathbb{N}$ as $N = $ (some function of $\epsilon$ and $x$).  Now for a $n>N$ we have 
\begin{align*}
 |f_n(x) - 1/x| = \left| \frac{n}{nx+1} - 1/x \right| = \frac{1}{x(1+nx)}\le \frac{1}{x(1+N x)} \le \cdots \le \epsilon
\end{align*}

So you need to find the function and fill in the ellipses.

Comment: the point wise limit is $1/x$ not 0

Comment: Yes @Rise the pointwise limit is $1/x$ not $0$

Comment: But thats exactly where I'm getting stuck

Comment: What if you tried to find the $N$ for which $\frac{1}{x(1+Nx)} = \epsilon$?

Comment: oh yes. thank you @fred !!

Comment: No problem, sorry for the initial mistake.